# Form field not recognized in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a form with a cs codebehind file. In my aspx page, I have this field:

```
<input runat="server" id="emailField" name="email" placeholder="jsmith@gmail.com" type="email"  required="required"/>
```

but when I try to reference it in my codebehind, my codebehind doesn't seem to recognize that it exists; I just get a syntax error. It's happening on all my other form fields too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to reference the field in your codebehind?

Comment: String toEmail = emailField.Value;

Comment: In a project that uses html5, why do you still use these old aspx files? Consider migrating to MVC with the razor engine.

Comment: @Yogu Could be an old project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

> 1 - Check to make sure your "form fields" have an `id` and
>   `runat="server"` attributes.
>
> 2 - Make sure there aren't any compilation errors. If there are fix
>   them so Visual Studio can generate the designer file necessary for intellisense.

Comment: apparently, I couldn't designate email as a type. I can reference the field now.

Answer (score 0):

Show the relevant code - how are you referencing it?

I have a hunch you're referencing it using `email`. Since the item is `runat="server"`, you can drop the name attribute and reference it using `emailField`.